# what does the variable lock mean in FileService?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

What does the variable boolean *lock* mean in [FileService.html#openReadChannel](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileService.html#openReadChannel%28com.google.appengine.api.files.AppEngineFile,%20boolean%29) ?

When I tried it with *false* I got an illegal state exception and when with *true* I din't get any. I was trying to upload a file.

What does this argument do ? I have read the doc but haven't understood it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to that page, it says

> lock - should the file be locked for exclusive access?

So it basically asks if you should be the only one who can access it.

If you use `false` then you'll probably try to write to it when someone else has access. I would assume that in almost all cases, you'll want `true`, since generally only one process writes to a file at a time.